# Remotely update game content in Unity3d for WebGL

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, server, webrequest, unity-webgl

I am very new to networking/client/server methods, I need to create a **WebGL** game using **Unity3d** which has a Client Login/Registration system.

Admin login should be able to access statistics of any registered users from a Dashboard but more importantly have authority to make changes to defined assets  in game such as Text, Images or Videos.

Can anyone help me draw a fundamental layout of what frameworks i need to use to implement this cross-domain data communication between Unity3d to Database and a server where assets are saved?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It only answers half of my question which is relevant to how to connect Unity with database.

The other half of my question is still not answered, which is, to have a dynamic method of changing the content of game after building it, by an external admin dashboard.

Comment: It says *"data communication between Unity3d to Database and a server where assets are saved"* The duplicate shows how to communicate with the database. The-same `WWW` or `UnityWebRequest` API mentioned there can be used to retrieve asset from the server too.